# Migrate Alt and Title text from a image file field

Tags: 8, files, migrations

I'm trying to migrate a multi-value D6 image field to D8. I've already migrated the files with d6_file and it worked. When I do the node migration with the image field works and I get all the values but the alt and title text are not migrated.

```
  field_image:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: field_image
    process:
      target_id:
        plugin: migration_lookup
        migration: upgrade_d6_file
        source: fid
      alt: alt
      title: title
```

Answer (score 0):

So this worked for me not sure why. But my file migration id was `upgrade_d6_file` and when I change this in line 54 of Drupal\file\Plugin\migrate\process\d6\FieldFile and ran the migration with the settings below I got the correctly referenced files and the alt/title text.

Diff

```
  // Configure the migration process plugin to look up migrated IDs from
  // a d6 file migration.
  $migration_plugin_configuration = $configuration + [
-   'migration' => 'd6_file',
+   'migration' => 'upgrade_d6_file',
    'source' => ['fid'],
  ];
```

Migrate yml

```
field_primary_image:
    plugin: d6_field_file
    source: field_image
    process:
      target_id:
        plugin: migration_lookup
        migration: upgrade_d6_file
        source: fid
      alt: alt
      title: title
```

Or even better is write your own process plugin like this: https://github.com/mikeryan776/d8-migrate-example-001/blob/master/migrate_carlyle/src/Plugin/migrate/process/CarlyleCckFile.php